# iOS app: access to Music storage allowed?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio-player

From my experience, it seems that most music-app solutions out there try to reinvent the wheel (creating a new player, that the user would need to start using instead of the iOS default one). So I'm wondering: is it because each application has its own way to access/modify the Music data?

In short: **can an iOS app add or remove music from the device in order for the *default* iOS music player to discover the new tracks?** If yes, where is the documentation about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps cannot add music to the iOS Music Player.  This is so that the only way to get music onto the default phone player is via iTunes.  This protects Apple's revenue from music, so you can't blame them really for doing this.

If there was a way, those apps you've seen would use it!